# Liferay Spring MVC Edit Mode

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay

This is my @RequestMapping("VIEW"). If the param is null. it will direct to edit mode

```
@Controller(value = "viewController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class viewController {
    @RenderMapping
     public void handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model){
            PortletMode mode = request.getPortletMode();
            PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();
            String server = prefs.getValue("server", "");
            request.setAttribute("server", server);
            System.out.println("server: " +server)`enter code here`;
            if(server == null || server == "")
            {
               //go to edit mode
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set default value for `server` preference property?

Comment: how? sorry this is my first time in liferay

Comment: first portlet deploy should be in edit mode first.

Comment: Like this `String server = prefs.getValue("server", "default_server");`

Comment: The user will be the one to put a value in the server, so if there's no value yet. it should be direct to edit mode (@RequestMapping("EDIT")) for preference. i dont know how to call that controller (editController.class)

Comment: I think, this is not a good approach to redirect user to edit screen for no value of server. Rather, I would you to set default value of the preference property.

Comment: Edit mode should be the first controller to be called. how can i do that? then after the entering the need parameters it will redirect in view mode